# Apify-Client having trouble working with React

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, apify

I hope you are having a fantastic day.

I am using this API: https://apify.com/petrpatek/covid-19-aggregator/api, for the first time, and I am having some issues getting it to work with React. This is the file where I am making my API call:

```
const ApifyClient = require('apify-client');
require('dotenv').config({ path: `${__dirname}/../../.env` });

const client = new ApifyClient({
  token: process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN,
});

const input = {};

const getItems = async () => {
  // Run the actor and wait for it to finish
  const run = await client.actor('petrpatek/covid-19-aggregator').call(input);

  // Fetch and print actor results from the run's dataset (if any)
  console.log('Results from dataset');
  const { items } = await client.dataset(run.defaultDatasetId).listItems();
  //   console.log(items);
  items.forEach((item) => {
    console.dir(item);
  });

  return items;
};

getItems();

// export default getItems();
```

Most of the above is just copy-pasted from the API docs, this file has no problems running as a standalone, if I run `node apify.js`, it returns the correct data as I expect:
[correct data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW2F3.png)

However when I try to run it inside of a React component, like so:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import CountryCard from '../components/countryCard';
import Header from '../components/header';
import getItems from '../APIs/apify';

const AllCountriesPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="allCountriesPage">
      <Header />
      <CountryCard className="bannerCountry" />
      <p className="allCountriesText">All countries</p>
      <div className="allCountriesContainer">
        {/* Some kind of for loop */}
        <CountryCard />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllCountriesPage;
```

It throws the following error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o917B.png)

At first, I thought this was just a problem with the dependencies, but I do have them installed, or the file would not be running by itself, also this is my package.js file:

```
{
  "name": "catalogue-of-statistics",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "apify-client": "^1.2.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^21.0.0",
    "stylelint-csstree-validator": "^1.9.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.19.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I am uncommenting `export default getItems` and commenting `getItems()` before switching to the react implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I see my colleague replied to you over our Discord.

For others:

```
You need to add mainFields: ['browser', 'main', 'module'], to your webpack config. The order is important. main needs to go before module. See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfields
```

Answer (score 0):

As Lukas was saying above, the Apify team answered my question directly in their discord, so I want to put the solution here if someone comes across it in the future.

You need to go to `node_modules -> react_scripts -> config -> webpack.config.js` inside the `resolve: { ... }` object, add this line: `mainFields: ['browser', 'main', 'module'],` make sure that `main` is before `module`.